# Finding the base file name

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

What the easiest way to find the base filename in progress.

I have:

```
 /tmp/admin/run/test.txt
```

and I want:

```
 test.txt
```

10.2b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the R-INDEX() function to find the right-most "/".

```
define variable path as character no-undo initial "/tmp/admin/run/test.txt".

display
  path format "x(60)" skip 
  substring( path, r-index( path, "/" ) + 1 ) format "x(60)"
.
```

Comment: You have a ) out of place but after that it works great. Thanks!

Comment: This also only works for unix-style directory separators - windows uses "\".

Comment: Oops, fixed.  The code is also rather light on error checking and such -- the point was just to show the general idea.